# Disproving Big-oh

Tags: computational-complexity

How would you disprove the following:
$ \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, n^n \in O(n^k) $.

I am aware that I have to pick a value for $n \in \mathbb{N} $ that will give us $n^n > c*n^k$ but I can't seem to figure out how to pick such a value when c and k are universally quantified.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you come up with a specific counterexample?

Comment: No actually. But if I were to prove it, how would I pick values for k and c that do not depend on n?

Comment: Is the statement you are trying to disprove $\exists k$ such that $\forall n$ $n^{n} \in O(n^{k})$ or is it $\forall n$ $\exists k$ such that $n^{n} \in O(n^{k})$?

Comment: The first one, $\exists k$ such that $\forall n$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k,c>0$. Then if $n>2$ and $n>k+\log_2(c)$ we get $n^n=n^{n-k}n^k>2^{\log_2(c)}n^k=cn^k$. Take, for example, $n=\lfloor\max\{2,k+\log_2(c)\}\rfloor+1$.